# C++ compilation issue on class inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

As I am fairly new in inheritancee, I have some compilation error which I do not know how to resolve. I have no where to go to and hence I come here. My '=' assignment operator is also wrong, just that I do not have the complication error to show. I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks!

Compilation error:

```
 main.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Line&)’:

 main.cpp:56:17: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are 

 ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘Point’)
 stream << "(" << p.p1 << ", " << p.p2 << ")" << endl;
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~

 In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc- 
 cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/iostream:39:0,
             from main.cpp:1:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/ostream:108:7: note: 
 candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& 
 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, 
 _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, 
 _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = 
 std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type 
 = std::basic_ostream<char>]
   operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
   ^~~~~~~~
```

Main.cpp

```
class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}


};

class Linee : public Point 
{ 
 private:
    Point p1;
    Point p2;
public:
    Line(const Point & p1, const Point & p2 ) : p1(p1), p2(p2) {}

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Line &p);
    Line& operator = (const Line &a);       
    void Draw();

};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Line &p) {
    stream << "(" << p.p1 << ", " << p.p2 << ")" << endl;
    return stream;
}

Line& operator = (const Line &a)
{
    p1 = a.p1;
    p2 = a.p2;
    return *this;
}
    void Line::Draw() {
cout << "Line" << "drawing" << endl;
}

int main() 
{
Line l1;                //Output: Line construction
std::cout << l1;        //Output: Line (0,0) (0,0)
l1.Draw();              //Output: Line drawing

Line l2(Point(), 
Point(100,100));    //Output: Line construction
std::cout << l2;        //Output: Line (0,0) (100,100)
l1 = l2;
std::cout << l1;        //Output: Line (0,0) (100,100)
}
```

Comment: I think you have misspelled `Line` in `class Linee`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stream << "(" << p.p1 << ", " << p.p2 << ")" << endl;
```

Since `p.p1` and `p.p2` are of type `Point`, this code can only work if `Point` implements an appropriate `operator<<`. It clearly doesn't.

Try to point (hehe) to the code that prints the `x` or `y` coordinates of a `Point`. You can't do it because there is no such code.

Comment: Hi @David Schwartz, But will it output the same as what is shown in the main if I do that? I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Do you understand what I'm saying? A `Point` has an `x` and a `y` member. To output a `Point`, you need to output these coordinates. Where is the code that does that? It's missing, so the compiler is complaining that it can't figure out how to print a point.

Comment: Ohh sorry. My bad. Ok. I get it now. Thanks. Can I ask you one more thing, its regarding the '=' assignment operator. It doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What does it do or not do? Do you get a compilation error? If so, what error?

Comment: shwartz Well it gives me a compilation error. Saying that it must be a non static member function for this ->  Line& operator = (const Line &a)

Comment: Do you understand what that means? It's the same type of error -- where's the code to copy the `x` and `y` coordinate values when you do `p1 = a.p1;`?

Comment: Right ok. Thanks. After making that change, I'm still getting that same error tho. Nvm, I'll go figure it out somehow.